# Black screen after login when installing Mesa 10 from source

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, install-from-source, mesa

I wanted to update my Mesa version to 10.0, so I compiled it from source, installed it, rebooted and when I logged in, I had a black screen with only my mouse visible. I have reinstalled Ubuntu 13.10 a few times now, and tried to install Mesa 10.0 again, and every time I get the same issue. I can just reinstall Ubuntu now, but that doesn't solve the problem of not having Mesa version 10.0. Does anybody know how to install Mesa 10.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit without getting that black screen on login?

Thanks!